# Elements row sum function. VBA; MS Excel

Tags: vba, excel, math

I need someone to tell me why I get

```
compile error : Expected array
```

as soon as I try to use my function and what should be changed to get the result. As much as I understand there's no need in array usage according to task(explained below the code).

```
Public Function papild(x)
    Dim s As Double, A As Double
    Dim P As Integer
    s = 0.5 + (x - system.Math.Pi) / 1
    A = (x - system.Math.Pi) / 1
    P = 2
    Do While Abs(A) > 0.0001
        A = -A * (x - system.Math.Pi) * (x - system.Math.Pi) / P(P + 1)
        s = s + A
        P = P + 1
    Loop
    papild = s
End Function
```

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
I'll try my best to explain the task of mine, I hope it would be useful for you to point out what's done wrong.

*** Conditions: using ^ operator is forbidden. ***
There's : **Elements row sum formula** - [image] and argument variation range - (-π/2) to (π/2) [Step: π/30].
My actions: one column is being used for argument value (first cell(@ Formula bar) =PI()/-2));every next cell is (@Formula bar) ="cell above" + PI()/30.;Writing the code(above) and calling the function in second column, using appropriate column one cell as function argument.
Thanks in advance.
(Sorry for my poor English, especially for math terminology)

Comment: when you get the error it highlights this part of the formula `P(P + 1)`  This is array notation.  I think you want `P * (P + 1)`

Comment: thanks! Array expectation's gone, now there's #VALUE @ cell where function's being called. :(

Comment: change all your `system.Math.Pi` to `Application.WorksheetFunction.Pi()`

Comment: Tell me if I'm wrong, it was ---
 A = (x - system.Math.Pi); now it's ---  A = (x - Application.WorksheetFunction.Pi()) . If it's correct, add sys.math.Pi got changed but #value's still there.

Comment: There must be something wrong with the formula itself, if you put in `=papild(3)` it works with my answer below.  but only that number.  All others error.

Comment: Actually upon further testing it only works with numbers that are +/- 1 from Pi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as per the comments:

```
Public Function papild(x)
    Dim s As Double, A As Double
    Dim P As Integer
    s = 0.5 + (x - Application.WorksheetFunction.Pi()) / 1
    A = (x - Application.WorksheetFunction.Pi()) / 1
    P = 2
    Do While Abs(A) > 0.0001
        A = -A * (x - Application.WorksheetFunction.Pi()) * (x - Application.WorksheetFunction.Pi()) / P ^ (P + 1)
        s = s + A
        P = P + 1
    Loop
    papild = s
End Function
```

Comment: Just 've checked it. Now there's a problem with formula - it doesnt take negative args. Thanks for your time, i'll try to fix the formula for now.

Comment: let's also use `Dim pi As Double: pi = Application.WorksheetFunction.pi`, and use `pi` throughout the UDF...

Comment: #value error is gone, but using ^ operator is forbidden for this task. Maybe  I just figured that my whole approach was wrong - I'm using int P as control for denominator. Example - second element(further el.) denominator is 3!(factorial) and P == 2, so P * (P + 1) returns 2 * 3 = 3!; Third el. denominator is 5! and P == 3 that's where my P * (P + 1) , while 3 * 4 != 5!. So I'll start over tomorrow, I've been struggling with this task for a while, got to take some rest.

Comment: There's even more small mistakes. I guess case is closed, got to start over for sure. Scott and @MacroMarc thank you.